# What does #describe and #it methods do in TDD react testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, chai, enzyme

I'm learning TDD with React from this [site](http://thereignn.ghost.io/a-step-by-step-tdd-approach-on-testing-react-components-using-enzyme/), but don't understand how the author got `describe` and *it*, aren't these usually from Jasmine? I don't see this package in the author's node_modules at his github nor does his `tests.js` import anything that looks like `describe` or `it`. Where are these two methods coming from?

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';


describe('Test suite for User component', () => {
  it('UserComponent should exist', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<User />)
    expect(wrapper).to.exist;
  });
});
```

Comment: They are coming from `mocha`. The author has already added it in the package.json to run the tests using mocha. Check this https://github.com/r31gN/tdd-react-enzyme-article/blob/master/package.json#L6.

Comment: i notice that he uses #childAt too, but he didn't import that from enzyme, how is that possible?

Comment: I think you got it wrong. It's a method on wrapper object.

Answer (score 3):

If that is the only `it()` statement that you are going to be using in your test suite, you do not really need the `describe()` block.

The `describe()` construct does indeed exist in Jest, it exists in Mocha as well.

The `describe()` function is used to group together certain sets of tests that have some common setup and tear down for each of them. This is why I said, based on the code you pasted, if you have nothing further to test, you do not need that `describe()` function.

So when you run `create-react-app` one of the libraries that got loaded automatically was the Jest test suite.

I would also rewrite that test, instead of UserComponent should exist, I would do

```
it('shows a user component', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<User />);
  expect(wrapper.find(User).length).toEqual(1);
});
```

So this is where I recommend to not just follow tutorials, but look up the documentation of the tools they are having you utilize in these tutorials. In the case of Enzyme, there is a really nice method called `find()` to find the component and it offers an array so you can add on `.length` and since its just one component of User you can add at the end `.toEqual(1);`